# Use one user on both remote and local connections

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to connect to a remote server and use that for logins. This was not particularly hard.

```
Remote = DDP.connect('http://somesite.com');
Accounts.connection = Remote;
Meteor.users = new Mongo.Collection('users', Remote);
```

However, when I call meteor methods on my *local* code (there are multiple servers, but one login), it does not recognize the user.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'start': function () {
    if (!this.userId) {
      // ...
    } else {
      throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'Unauthorized');
    }
  }
});
```

This always results in an error, despite being logged in.

How can I set my local user to the same user as the remote user?

Answer (score 1):

Let's rename the following:

- `Remote` => `Login Server`
- `local`  => `Default Server`  This is where you call the Methods

I think you are better served by logging into `Default Server`, which then relays the login attempt to the `Login Server`.
This way you will be logged in on `Default Server` (if `Login Server` confirms the credentials are valid) when you use the `Meteor.Methods` that are on `Default Server`.

[Accounts.validateLoginAttempt](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt) allows you to run arbitrary code in a callback on a LoginAttempt, allowing you to pass the validation from `Default Server` to `Login Server`:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt) {
    //psuedocode block
    var res = LoginServer_Login(attempt.methodArguements)
    if (res === true) return true;  // Login Success
    else              return false; // Login Failed
  });
}
```

I'm not sure of the best way to implement LoginServer_Login func, though I'd try using HTTP.post to communicate with `Login Server` first (and recommend using [restivus](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus) on the Login Server, it will give you authentication routes out of the box).

I just came across this package: `admithub:shared-auth`
It requires a shared db between the two meteor apps though.
Beyond this, you probably need to look into full SSO solutions.